# How to insert multiple rows into foreign key table, with list of primary key table rows using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, triggers

I am trying to insert multiple rows with the same data and different vendor id, those vendor ids taken to XML list but not apply to  while loop please give me solution.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trginsert] 
ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @sal INT

    SET @Name = (SELECT i.Emp_name FROM inserted AS i)
    SET @sal = (SELECT i.Emp_Sal FROM inserted AS i)

    DECLARE @count INT
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'number of vendors' 
                  FROM AspNetUsers 
                  WHERE ERPMainCustID IS NOT NULL)

    DECLARE @id INT
    DECLARE @ids XML

    SET @ids = (SELECT id AS [*] 
                FROM AspNetUsers 
                WHERE ERPMainCustID IS NOT NULL
                FOR XML PATH('ID'), ROOT('IDs'), TYPE)

    WHILE @id >= @count
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Employee_Test 
        VALUES (@Name, @sal, @id)
    END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: please give me to the solution

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server trigger is run not once per row, but once per statement - so if your `INSERT` statement inserts 10 rows at once (e.g. by using a `SELECT .... FROM ...` clause), then you get the trigger called **once**, but `Inserted` will contain **10 rows**. You need to take that into account when writing your trigger!

You need to approach `Inserted` in a set-based fashion - don't expect it to contain only a single row.... also: there's really no point in first selecting those ID's from `AspNetUsers` into a XML variable, and then doing a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) WHILE loop over them to insert..... again: use the proper **set-based** approach!

In the end, your trigger might look something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trginsert] 
ON [dbo].[Employee_Test]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    -- you should *ALWAYS* spell out the columns you want to insert into!
    -- since you didn't mention them, this is *just my GUESS* - adapt as needed!
    INSERT INTO Employee_Test (Name, Salary, EmpId)
        -- grab the inserted rows from "Inserted"
        SELECT
            i.Emp_name, i.Emp_Sal, u.ERPMainCustID
        FROM
            Inserted i
        -- cross join them against all the "ERPMainCustID" values from "AspNetUsers"
        CROSS JOIN
            AspNetUsers u
        WHERE
            u.ERPMainCustID IS NOT NULL
```